# How to create 2 different marker with 2 different custominfowindow in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm having problem creating my own CustomInfoWindow, when i am trying to set second custominfowindow in marker, all marker used last custominfowindow as default.

Comment: Add your code here, it may help to resolve issue easily

Comment: add some more code information

Answer (score 0):

```
mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(pos)
    .title("title")
    .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow1)));


mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(pos)
    .title("title")
    .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow2)));
```